# How to capitalize a word if it exits in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I need some help capitalizing a word from a string if it exists in an array (Ruby)

```
phrase = "Love and War fail"
array = ['a', 'and', 'the', 'but']
```

My initial thoughts would be to create a loop that cycles through each item in the array, but how can I create a conditional (ie: capitalize only word is in array) so that it capitalizes only word in the array?

Thanks for the help ! :)

Comment: `array = ["a, and, the, but]` has syntax error. What is it, an array of strings, or an array of one string?

Comment: google terms: "ruby string split", "ruby array include?"

Comment: Please consider selecting the one and only answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
c_words = phrase.split & array 
c_words.each{ |w| phrase.sub!(/\b#{w}/, w.capitalize) } 
phrase
# => "Love And War fail"
```

Or as Glupo suggested in comments below:

```
array.each{ |w| phrase.sub!(/\b#{w}/, w.capitalize) }
```

Comment: No need to split the phrase. Iterating straight through array would also work. `array.each{ |w| phrase.sub!(/\b#{w}/, w.capitalize) }`